# Minimum growing conditions of a given plant

Tags: biochemistry, microbiology, agriculture

Micro-algae are organisms that can grow in aquatic environments and use light and carbon dioxide (CO2) to create biomass. Researches showed that Micro-algae biomass can be used as bio-fertilizer.

My mission is : to find which plants in the world are best suited to arid climates and to arid soil that was treated using the Micro-algae biomass.

This is my approach on how to accomplish my mission:

I' m into collecting chemical characteristics data of the soil , chemical characteristics data of the micro-algae biomass and other environmental factors like the temperature, rainfall and humidity of this environment. I want to use this data to determine whether a given plant can survive (adapt) in this environment. So I want to compare this environment (arid + Micro-algae biomass applied) characteristics (N, P, K, Temps, humidity....) to the minimum growing conditions of the given plant .

My problem is : How to determine that minimum growing conditions of a given plant in terms of the needed nutrients (N, P, K) , Temperature, water etc...?

I'm open to any biology/math resources and any other inspirations or approaches.

Comment: Depends very much on the plant you are interested in. Better studied ones such as crop plants or things like *Arabidopsis* will be well characterized; others not so much. Don;t discount things like formation of mycorrhyzal networks.

Comment: OK, Currently, I'm targeting plants that are food for humans/animals. Is there any data source of plants that are well characterized (like potato, Onion...). BTW I'm not a biologist I'm a Data Scientist.@bob1

Comment: We see this sort of thing quite a lot. To actually answer this question you *will* need to learn a lot of biology.  Is there a database: probably not (AFAIK), you would have to dig the literature for yourself, and you will find it mostly comes in the form of "plant variety (not species, individual variety within species) grown under abnormal X, but "normal" conditions Y,Z,A,B,C... etc". You might find ranges for some variables in reviews or horticulture textbooks/manuals/gardening guides. Seed packets often have climate ranges for sowing, but you would need to dig climate conditions.

Comment: Ok I got this. I think I will just start reading papers and books instead of wasting my time looking for a database. thank you so much @bob1